# AWS VPC : Enable public access for application(s) running on private ip addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, proxy, amazon-vpc

We have a few Couchbase databases running on EC2 instance(s) running within a AWS VPC. Our apps are on a different VPC. The app layer talks to the Database via VPC peering.

Couchbase provides a web interface on port 8091. We would like to access this web interface to do some administrative operation(s) from our laptops. What would be the best possible to access this web interface, with low cost a priority?

Is enabling VPN my only option? Or is there any other way to do this? If so, could anyone point me to document(s)/reference(s), configuration?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to make "access this database console" a bit more clear? Is that the RDS console? Some PHP application? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Tim- These are Couchbase servers and you can access the web console on port 8091

Comment: VPN is the smart answer. Exposing your admin console to the Internet violates every security best practice.

Comment: @var I think we need more information. You said you have instances running within a VPC, but virtually everything in AWS runs within a VPC. Do you mean the databases run in a VPC with no internet gateway / internet connection. I've edited your question, and I encourage you to further edit it to increase clarity and provide more information. We can't help you if we don't have all the information. Typically the answer is just access the database console over the internet using an internet gateway, but there are security considerations.

Answer (score 0):

VPN is the secure option for connecting or making your instance available so you can connect from your site/home. But you can also connect to it using the public IP address of your instance and configure the instance security to allow the communications, just bear in mind that this exposes your instance to the public and is less secure (and can be attacked some way).

Answer (score 0):

The VPN is one answer, but personally I think it might be a bit much for infrequent management of a database. I'm not too familier with Couchbase, but hopefully you aren't in the console making changes every day. If I were setting this up, I'd probably lean towards running an SSH daemon on some non-standard port, then setting up ssh tunnelling from my desktop to the Couchbase server.

`ssh -N -L 8091:10.0.0.1:8091 ec2-user@public-ip-of-ssh-server -p 5678`

You can use a security group to enable and disable access to the SSH port, and restrict access to only your public IP (if you are the only one using it). Just remember to disable the security group when you are finished managing the database.